# Convert large csv to hdf5

Tags: python, csv, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have a 100M line csv file (actually many separate csv files) totaling 84GB. I need to convert it to a HDF5 file with a single float dataset. I used **h5py** in testing without any problems, but now I can't do the final dataset without running out of memory.

How can I write to HDF5 without having to store the whole dataset in memory? I'm expecting actual code here, because it should be quite simple.

I was just looking into **pytables**, but it doesn't look like the array class (which corresponds to a HDF5 dataset) can be written to iteratively. Similarly, **pandas** has `read_csv` and `to_hdf` methods in its `io_tools`, but I can't load the whole dataset at one time so that won't work. Perhaps you can help me solve the problem correctly with other tools in pytables or pandas.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Use `append=True`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/io.html#id2) in the call to `to_hdf`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = '/tmp/test.h5'

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df)
#    A  B
# 0  0  1
# 1  2  3
# 2  4  5
# 3  6  7
# 4  8  9

# Save to HDF5
df.to_hdf(filename, 'data', mode='w', format='table')
del df    # allow df to be garbage collected

# Append more data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2))*10, columns=['A', 'B'])
df2.to_hdf(filename, 'data', append=True)

print(pd.read_hdf(filename, 'data'))
```

yields

```
    A   B
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7
4   8   9
0   0  10
1  20  30
2  40  50
3  60  70
4  80  90
```

Note that you need to use `format='table'` in the first call to `df.to_hdf` to make the table appendable. Otherwise, the format is `'fixed'` by default, which is faster for reading and writing, but creates a table which can not be appended to.

Thus, you can process each CSV one at a time, use `append=True` to build the hdf5 file. Then overwrite the DataFrame or use `del df` to allow the old DataFrame to be garbage collected.

---

Alternatively, instead of calling `df.to_hdf`, you could [append to a HDFStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/io.html#table-format):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = '/tmp/test.h5'
store = pd.HDFStore(filename)

for i in range(2):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)) * 10**i, columns=['A', 'B'])
    store.append('data', df)

store.close()

store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
data = store['data']
print(data)
store.close()
```

yields

```
    A   B
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7
4   8   9
0   0  10
1  20  30
2  40  50
3  60  70
4  80  90
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be possible with PyTables. You'll need to use the [EArray](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#earrayclassdescr) class though.

As an example, the following is a script I wrote to import chunked training data stored as `.npy` files into a single `.h5` file.

```
import numpy
import tables
import os

training_data = tables.open_file('nn_training.h5', mode='w')
a = tables.Float64Atom()
bl_filter = tables.Filters(5, 'blosc')   # fast compressor at a moderate setting

training_input =  training_data.create_earray(training_data.root, 'X', a,
                                             (0, 1323), 'Training Input',
                                             bl_filter, 4000000)
training_output = training_data.create_earray(training_data.root, 'Y', a,
                                             (0, 27), 'Training Output',
                                             bl_filter, 4000000)

for filename in os.listdir('input'):
    print "loading {}...".format(filename)
    a = numpy.load(os.path.join('input', filename))
    print "writing to h5"
    training_input.append(a)

for filename in os.listdir('output'):
    print "loading {}...".format(filename)
    training_output.append(numpy.load(os.path.join('output', filename)))
```

Take a look at the docs for detailed instructions, but very briefly, the `create_earray` function takes 1) a data root or parent node; 2) an array name; 3) a datatype atom; 4) a shape with a `0` in the dimension you want to expand; 5) a verbose descriptor; 6) a [compression filter](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/helper_classes.html#the-filters-class); and 7) an expected number of rows along the expandable dimension. Only the first two are required, but you'll probably use all seven in practice. The function accepts a few other optional arguments as well; again, see the docs for details.

Once the array is created, you can use its `append` method in the expected way.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a very large *single* CSV file, you may want to stream the conversion to hdf, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import clear_output

CHUNK_SIZE = 5000000 

filename = 'data.csv'
dtypes = {'latitude': float, 'longitude': float}

iter_csv = pd.read_csv(
    filename, iterator=True,
    dtype=dtypes, encoding='utf-8', chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE)

cnt = 0
for ix, chunk in enumerate(iter_csv):
    chunk.to_hdf(
        "data.hdf", 'data', format='table', append=True)
    cnt += CHUNK_SIZE
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(f"Processed {cnt:,.0f} coordinates..")
```

Tested with a 64GB CSV file and 450 Million coordinates (about 10 Minutes conversion).