# Process a LOT of data

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, bigdata

So I'm working with parametric energy simulations and ended up with 500GB+ of data stored in `.CSV` files. I need to be able to process all this data to compare the results and gain insights of the influence of different parameters.

Each csv file name contains information of the parameters used for the simulation so I can not merge the files.

I normally loaded the .csv files to python using pandas and defining a Class. but now (with all this data) there is not enough memory to do this.

Can you point me out a way to process this data? I need to be able to do plots and compare the csv files.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In short, you need lazy evaluation of data. You may want to research on a means of retrieving your data points one by one (or by batch), but naturally this depends on your particular problem (which you haven't explained to us).

Comment: Maybe helpful: [“Large data” work flows using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas/14268804#14268804)

Answer (score 0):

[Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203161/convert-large-csv-to-hdf5) the csv files to [hdf5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5/), which was created to deal with massive and complex datasets.  It works with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5) as well as [other](http://www.pytables.org/FAQ.html) [libraries](http://www.h5py.org/).

Comment: I've converted the files and have separated 120gb hdf5 files. but it takes forever to query. for example: store.keys()[0] takes around 3 minutes. Any idea why?